# How to concatenate string continuously in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $test = ' /clothing/men/tees';

    $req_url = explode('/', $test);

    $c = count($req_url);

    $ex_url = 'http://www.test.com/';

    for($i=1; $c > $i; $i++){

        echo '/'.'<a href="'.$ex_url.'/'.$req_url[$i].'">

                <span>'.ucfirst($req_url[$i]).'</span>

            </a>';
        //echo '<br/>'.$ex_url;....//last line
    }
?>
```

OUTPUT - 1 //when comment last line

```
/ Clothing / Men / Tees
```

OUTPUT - 2 //when un-comment last line $ex_url shows

```
/ Clothing 
http://www.test.com// Men 
http://www.test.com// Tees 
http://www.test.com/
```

**1. Required output** -

In span - / Clothing / Men / Tees and *last element should not be clickable*

and link should created in this way

```
http://www.test.com/clothing/Men/tees -- when click on Tees

http://www.test.com/clothing/Men --  when click on Men
```

...respectively

**2. OUTPUT 2 why it comes like that**

Comment: Output 1 does not work?

Comment: An array starts at 0 not at 1

Comment: @Naruto The string starts with a slash as well...

Comment: @Naruto i know that. but in my case `$req_url[0]` is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <?php
    $test = '/clothing/men/tees';
    $url = 'http://www.test.com';
    foreach(preg_split('!/!', $test, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $e) {
    $url .= '/'.$e;
        echo '/<a href="'.$url.'"><span>'.ucfirst($e).'</span></a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Output:

```
/Clothing/Men/Tees
```

HTML output:

```
/<a href="http://www.test.com/clothing"><span>Clothing</span></a>/<a href="http://www.test.com/clothing/men"><span>Men</span></a>/<a href="http://www.test.com/clothing/men/tees"><span>Tees</span></a>
```

Comment: thanks..can u explain your code? whats wrong when i comment last line?

Comment: @Prashant I'm not an expert but I know something about HTML DOM structure, whenever you want to display elements inline, close to each other, you should render them inline only. Like <a>1</a><a>2</a>. You cann't use <br> tag, this is use for breaking line

Comment: `preg_split('!/!', $test, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` explain this

Comment: @Prashant `preg_split` — Split string by a regular expression,
`'!/!'` pattern to search for, you can also use '/\//',
`$test` - your string,
`-1` - Limit (-1, 0, NULL No Limit),
`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` - return only non-empty 
For more information you should visit real source http://docs.php.net/preg_split

Comment: i have `' /clothing/men/tees/'` this. output i got `home /clothing/men` . i dont want space before clothing

Comment: @Prashant `trim($string)` -  before concatenation and also check your code. I think somewhere you are including space. Or share you code

Comment: last element should not be clickable...how can i do that?

Comment: i already share my code. which is in question. if i get `/ Clothing / Men / Tees` this then tees not be clickable. if this `/ Clothing / Men ` men should not be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `foreach()` to iterate the array and you'll have to keep track of the path after the url. Try it like so (tested and working code):

```
<?php

    $test = '/clothing/men/tees';
    $ex_url = 'http://www.test.com';
    $items = explode('/', $test);
    array_shift($items);

    $path = '';
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $path .= '/' . $item;
        echo '/ <a href="' . $ex_url . $path . '"><span>' . ucfirst($item) . '</span></a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php

$test = '/clothing/men/tees';
$req_url = explode('/', ltrim($test, '/'));
$ex_url = 'http://www.test.com/';

$stack = array();
$reuslt = array_map(function($part) use($ex_url, &$stack) {
    $stack[] = $part;
    return sprintf('<a href="%s%s">%s</a>', $ex_url, implode('/', $stack), ucfirst($part));
}, $req_url);


print_r($reuslt);
```

Comment: your code show error `Message : syntax error, unexpected '['`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $sTest= '/clothing/men/tees';
    $aUri= explode( '/', $sTest );
    $sBase= 'http://www.test.com';  // No trailing slash

    $sPath= $sBase;  // Will grow per loop iteration
    foreach( $aUri as $sDir ) {
        $sPath.= '/'. $sDir;
        echo ' / <a href="'. $sPath.'">'. ucfirst( $sDir ). '</a>';  // Unnecessary <span>
    }
?>
```